# JAVA GENERICS ERROR: have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Tags: java, generics, comparable

For fun I'm creating a sorting framework to better understand the various sorting algorithms.  And, I'm trying to make it generic enough so that it can sort anything that implements an interface that extends the comparable interface.  However, the java compiler isn't happy with me.

Here's my interface:

```
public interface Sorter<C extends Comparable<C>>
{
    void sort(C[] comparables);

    void sort(C[] comparables, Comparator<C> comparator);
}
```

And, here's my abstract class that implements that interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractSort<C extends Comparable<C>> implements Sorter
{
    protected abstract void doSort(C[] comparables, Comparator<C> comparator);

    final public void sort(C[] comparables)
    {
        sort(comparables, new Comparator<C>()
        {
            public int compare(C left, C right)
            {
                return left.compareTo(right);
            }
        });
    }

    final public void sort(C[] comparables, Comparator<C> comparator)
    {
        doSort(comparables, comparator);
    }
}
```

And, here are the errors I'm getting:

```
java: name clash: sort(C[]) in AbstractSort and sort(java.lang.Comparable[]) in Sorter have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Error:(25, 23) java: name clash: sort(C[],java.util.Comparator<C>) in AbstractSort and sort(java.lang.Comparable[],java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Comparable>) in Sorter have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: All right, you are getting that. But what is it about it that is unclear to you? You don't know how  to make it generic enough so that it can sort anything that implements an interface that extends the comparable interface?

Comment: Also, you might want to move the generic type erasure only to the first `sort` method. The second method should be applicable, even if `C` does not implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing `implements Sorter<C>`. Without the type parameter, you use raw types, which disables certain aspects of generics for inherited methods. Specifically, with a raw super type, you only inherit erased method signatures. In your case, rather than inheriting the method `sort(C[] comparables)` your inherit a method `sort(Comparable[] comparables)`, which you can only override with an identical signature.

By specifying `Sorter<C>` as the supertype, you inherit a method `sort(C[] comparables), which you can override with the identical signature.

Pitfalls such as this is why the Java Language Specification recommends that raw types should only be used for interfacing with non-generic legacy code, and requires compilers to emit a warning when raw types are used.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Thanks for trying to help!

```
public interface Sorter<C extends Comparable<? super C>>
{
    void sort(C[] comparables);

    void sort(C[] comparables, Comparator<C> comparator);
}

public abstract class AbstractSort<C extends Comparable<? super C>> implements Sorter<C>
{
    protected abstract void concreteSort(C[] comparables, Comparator<C> comparator);

    final public void sort(C[] comparables)
    {
        sort(comparables, new Comparator<C>()
        {
            public int compare(Comparable left, Comparable right)
            {
                return left.compareTo(right);
            }
        });
    }

    final public void sort(C[] comparables, Comparator<C> comparator)
    {
        concreteSort(comparables, comparator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is both class and interface has the `void sort(C[])`, and they are conflicting. Try adding the `@Override` notation to the class methods.

I would say you are over-engineering this problem. I would prefer the interface, then you can do

```
Sorter<SortableClass> sorter = new QuickSorter<SortableClass>();
```

It is simple, and it will get to the point.