# name clash when trying to overwrite method

Tags: java, binary-tree, avl-tree, name-clash

this is my first post here, but I need help trying to figure out why my child class will not let me override the parent method.
 I was tasked to create a generic Binary Search Tree with some functionality. The next task was to create a generic AVL Tree and I decided to extend it from my custom Binary Search Tree to reuse code and simply add the rotation required to make it functional.
 **However when trying to overwrite the method, I keep getting a name clash error. And if I get rid of my Comparable interface extension in my AVLTree class and make my insert method generic, I get an argument mismatch error saying T cannot be converted to Comparable.** 
This is where I am stuck at, if anyone can offer any type of input it would be much appreciated.

```
public class BinaryTree <T extends Comparable<T>>{
Node Root;
public BinaryTree(){
    this.Root = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return this.Root == null;
}
public void insert(T data){       
    this.insert(data, this.Root);   
}
protected void insert(T data, Node<T> n){
    if(this.Root == null){
         this.Root = new Node(data);                  
    }
    if(data.equals(n.getData())){
        n.occurances++;
    }
    else if(data.compareTo(n.data) < 0){
        if(n.left != null)
            insert(data, n.left);            
        else            
            n.left = new Node(data);                            
    }
    else if(data.compareTo(n.data) > 0){
        if(n.right != null)
            insert(data, n.right);
        else
            n.right = new Node(data);                
    }
}
```

First attempt:

```
public class AVLTree <T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinaryTree{
private static final int ALLOWED_IMBALANCE = 1;

public void insert(T data){
    this.insert(data, this.Root);
}
```

Second attempt:

```
public class AVLTree  extends BinaryTree{
private static final int ALLOWED_IMBALANCE = 1;

public <T>void insert(T data){
    this.insert(data, this.Root);
}
```

[error for overwriting insert method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMtXi.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA GENERICS ERROR: have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651379/java-generics-error-have-the-same-erasure-yet-neither-overrides-the-other)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the type parameter of `BinaryTree`:

```java
//                                                               vvv
public class AVLTree <T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinaryTree<T> {
    private static final int ALLOWED_IMBALANCE = 1;

    @Override
    public void insert(T data){
        this.insert(data, this.Root);
    }
}
```

Comment: This made it work, thank you. I have to read up on generics a little more.